# git merge, bring back my changes

Tags: git

I'm not sure why this happened, but I worked on a branch called `Settings`.

This was maybe 2 wks ago. Then the `Settings` branch needed to be tested so I merged in the latest code from master so the merge would be less painful later.

Issue: For some reason, all the things I did originally on the `Settings` branch called clobbered.

Example: I had a `SettingsController.cs` file. Now when I merged in the latest from master, in SourceTree, I can see the SettingsController.cs file as deleted.

I'm not sure why this got deleted since I would think git would just apply whatever changes from master there were on top of my changes.

So I could do the down and dirty just copy and paste my code from `github.com`, but obviously that's not what I want to do.

So before I actually finish the merge, what's the best way to either do the merge correctly, or get out of this merge and bring in the last 2 wks of everyone's changes on master into my branch.

I typically do not have this problem when I pull in changes from another branch so I don't know why this time it was different.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the merge is not yet complete, use `git merge --abort`.

If it is complete, then you want to roll back to two weeks ago: lots of ways to do this, including reverting, reseting, and using various tools like `git gui` and `SourceTree`.  See [this very good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit) which details all the options and gives more references.